# Removing Extra characters from XML code with python or PowerShell

Tags: python, xml, powershell

I have many XML files saved in a structure like below.

```
#$Dummy$#<MAIN location='Loc-01'>
--- Other tags & Elements ---
</MAIN>
```

Notice the characters `#$Dummy$#` at the beginning. this is inserted purposefully, in-order to protect any intruders parsing & reading the data out. Apart from this, rest of the data is purely xml. And the files are saved with `.xml` extension. I Know how to parse xml with `Element Tree`.

In this case `Element Tree` throws the below error

`ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 2`

At present we open the files with any text editor & manually remove the characters. How can I remove this code with `Python` or `Power Shell`. as there are 1000's of files to parse.

Comment: By definition, XML files are well-formed. If those characters reside outside nodes like that, that is not an XML file. Consider checking how such materials were generated, hopefully with a compliant DOM library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this simple case ***text* processing via regular expressions** sounds like the right approach, as in the following **PowerShell** solution (by definition you cannot parse your files *as XML* as-is, given the extraneous text before the well-formed XML):

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.xml | ForEach-Object {
  $file = $_.FullName
  (Get-Content -Raw $file) -creplace '^#\$Dummy\$#' | Set-Content -NoNewLine $file
}
```

**Important**: [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) uses a *default* character encoding, irrespective of the original input file's encoding; in *Windows PowerShell*, that is the active ANSI code page; more sensibly, it is BOM-less UTF-8 in PowerShell *Core*. Use the `-Encoding` parameter as needed.

- `Get-ChildItem -Filter *.xml` returns all `*.xml` files in the current folder; tweak this command as needed; see [`Get-ChildItem`'s help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem).
- `Get-Content -Raw $file` reads the entire file into memory as a single string; see [`Get-Content`'s help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)
- `-creplace` case-sensitively (`c`) matches literal string `#$Dummy$#` string (escaped for the regex as `#\$Dummy\$#`, because `$` otherwise has special meaning) at the very start (`^`) of the input and implicitly replaces it with the empty string (since no replacement operand is given), which effectively *removes* it.

  - For more information about PowerShell's `-replace` operator, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) .
- `Set-Content` writes the (possibly modified) string back to `$file`. `-NoNewLine` (PSv5+) prevents an extra newline from getting appended.

Comment: @mklement()  this code works only when the `#$Dummy$#` characters are at the beginning. But, if it is at the end. it doesn't work. how to modify in such case?

Comment: @Tommy: use `-creplace '#\$Dummy\$#$'`

Comment: @Tommy: Glad to hear it; good point re extra newline: you need to use `Set-Content -NoNewLine` to prevent that (PowerShell v5+ only) - I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this in python if your character patterns are simple you can use the replace method as below if not you may have to import something like regex to complete the task. This also assumes all the files are in one directory.

```py
    import os
    path = "/directory"
    the_files = os.listdir(path)
    bad_chars = ["( )", " )( "]
    for a_file in the_files:
        file = open(a, 'r+')
        line = file.read
        for char in bad_chars:
            line.replace(chars)
        file.write(line)
        file.close()
```